# Orienting a matrix in 3d with XNA

Tags: c#, .net, matrix, 3d, xna

I need help orienting a matrix in 3d!

Hi everyone! I'm not new to programming, but I am new to 3d programming.

In my code, I have a view matrix. The view's target is always (0,0,0). And I also have a temporary matrix, which controls the camera (I take it's position and use it in the view matrix's CreateLookAt method).

This theory works, but not as I expected. I can successfully rotate the camera around the cube (left and right), and even pitching (up, down) works. But my problem occurs when I want to rotate left or right, while the camera is pitched up (is looking at the top of the object) or down (looking at object from below). It "rolls" the object. I would like it if the camera acted as if the targeted object didn't have a top or bottom side. If I pitch the camera up, and then right, the camera should rotate around my object and not roll on top of it. This is so hard to explain, cause my native is not english. Anyway, if you understood any of this :D then please reply. Thanx.

```
        tempcam *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(tempcam.Forward * 20);
        tempcam = Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(MathHelper.ToRadians((float)yangle),MathHelper.ToRadians((float)zangle), 0);
        tempcam *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(tempcam.Backward * 20);
        cameraposition = new Vector3(tempcam.M41, tempcam.M42, tempcam.M43);
        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraposition, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
```

Comment: try implementing this camera: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Tutorial_Arcball It will work just like Blender's camera

Comment: Blender's camera is exactly what I want to avoid! You can see, that no matter how you rotate the camera in blender, it always acts as if the model you are creating has a top side and a bottom side.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
view = Matrix.CreateRotationY(yangle) *
       Matrix.CreateRotationX(xangle) *
       Matrix.CreateTranslation(Vector3.Backward * 20.0f);
```

Comment: This would create roll also. However, consider editing your answer to put the pitch rotation before the yaw rotation, then it would not produce roll. here's a video I made some time ago to show why.  http://www.screencast.com/users/sh8zen/folders/Xna/media/929e0a9a-16d1-498a-b777-8b3d85fd8a00

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of a first person camera rather than a fixed target camera?

Comment: I wasn't thinking of any type of camera in particular, just looking at your code by itself.  Whenever you rotate around the world Y axis, then around the world X axis, that 2nd rotation will have both a local X and a local Z(roll) rotation component to it which will cause the appearance of roll. I'm not positive that's the exact problem the OP has but if it is, your code would answer it if you reverse the order of rotations.

Comment: I'm confused because I have this code working in one of my applications.  If I reverse the order as you say then the object rotates around the world y axis but the local x axis causing a roll

Comment: I just woke up, and I'll give your ideas a try. BTW, what's the name of the softwares, that are shown in those videos?

Comment: I mean the one with the moon example! :D

Comment: @gareththegeek  If we define roll as the resultant matrix's Right vector (row 1 of the basis vectors) as not being coplanar with the world's xz plane, then roll is most easily expressed with the Y value of that basis vector (result.M12) != to zero. But when result.M12 is == to 0.0f, then there is no roll. Your code causes view.M12 to have value other than 0 thus the matrix is in a rolled orientation. If you change it to: `view = Matrix.CreateRotationX(xangle) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(yangle) * yourSameTranslationBit;` then view.M12 will remain at 0 thus not in a rolled orientation.

Comment: @ZséliIstván  the video was done in 3ds max, it was made to help a friend understand what was going on with a project he was making.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after hours of frustration, I gave up went with the "blender" type camera. It worked perfectly. I left XNA and tried out the new unity engine. With unity, I achived much more, than I ever could in XNA. Anyway thanks everyone for the replies, I appreciate them and they were really helpful. I would give an UP flag, but I don't have enough rep. If someone can close this thread, please do so.